# PyMongo statistics

Tags: python, mongodb, statistics, pymongo

I am using PyMongo and have a collection with about 5 million entries. Each entry has a country code field.

What is the most elegant way (and best performance-wise?) to get a statistics like:

```
US - 302000
CA - 180000
IN - 160000
DE - 125000
...
```

Does MongoDB have a special kind of query for that or should I do it in a loop with an ordinary Python dictionary?

edit:
example of an entry:

```
update(
    {"id": user["id"]},
    {"$set": {
        ... some other fields
        "_country_code": "US",
        "_last_db_update": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
    }, upsert=True)
```

Comment: Could you please show an example of an entry in the collection?

Comment: OK, I have added one.

Comment: The numbers you are trying to get for each `_country_code` field are just how many documents with the country code are there?

Comment: Yes!
But the solution should be fully dynamic. I don't know which countries are included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a task for the [mongodb aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$_country_code", count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

will produce results like:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "US",
            "count" : 302000
        },
        {
            "_id" : "CA",
            "count" : 180000
        },
        ...
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The same query using pymongo:

```
db.command('aggregate', 'collection', pipeline=[{"$group": {"_id": "$_country_code", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, looks exactly like what I need! Thank you!